# Does the sample average of Pareto distributed variables converge?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

If I have a sample of iid  random variables $X_1, X_2, ... X_T$ from a Pareto distribution with $0<\alpha\le 1$ and $x_m>0$, as $N$ tends to infinity does the average mean sample converge to the expected value ? If so does it do it with probability 1 ?

Comment: Pareto distribution with $\alpha\le 1$ has infinite mean, so $S_n/n\to\infty$ almost surely.